# Can't understand the definition that a kernel function is positive-definite. What is the type of its arguments?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, products, positive-definite

I can't understand the solution to this example problem:

> Let $K_1:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary kernel function. Prove that $K_2(x,y)=a\cdot K_1^2(x,y)+b$, where $a,b$ are positive real numbers, is also a kernel function.

The presented solution first uses the fact that $K$ is a kernel function $\implies$ there is a mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ , $N\gg n$ such that $K(x,y)=\varphi(x)\cdot\varphi(y)$.

Then my notes from the lecture consist of a series of computations. In short:

$K_1(x,y)=\varphi_1(x)\cdot\varphi(y)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)\cdot(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\ldots+x_Ny_N)$

$K_2(x,y)=aK_1^2(x,y)+b=a(x_1y_1+\ldots+x_Ny_N)^2+b=a(x_1^2y_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2y_N^2+2x_1y_1x_2y_2+\ldots)+b=\varphi_2(x)\cdot\varphi_2(y)$

Where $\varphi_2(x)=\left(\sqrt ax_1^2,\sqrt ax_2^2,\ldots,\sqrt a x_N^2,\sqrt{2a}x_1x_2,\sqrt{2a}x_1x_3,\ldots,\sqrt b\right)$.

Now I have an annotation in my notes that I don't understand: Namely, that here we somehow used the fact that a kernel function is positive-definite, which means that the matrix $K(x_i,x_j)$ is positive definite.

...what?? What does this even mean: $K(x_i,x_j)$?? I thought that a kerner function accepts *vectors* as arguments, NOT elements of these vectors, and I'm interpreting $x_i,x_j$ to be elements of vectors! How can we construct a matrix of pairwise applications of $K$ to elements of a vector if $K$ accepts the vectors themselves and not their elements??

What does it mean that $K$ is positive definite and how to derive from this fact the shape of $\varphi_2$?

Comment: I'll be honest... my tagging of this question as 'operator-theory' and 'hilbert-spaces' was a lot *cargo-cult*-ish... I simply read that kernel functions are a part of these theories however I know little about these theories and I don't know if and why kernel functions are indeed part of these theories... Tl;dr: If my tagging is wrong, please retag.

Comment: The notation used in the notes is a bit confusing. When it says $K(x_i,x_j)$ is positive definite, superscripts should have been used instead of subscripts. So $x_i$'s are indeed vectors here.

Comment: If you consider $K$ as a function of two vectors, then of course its arguments are the vectors, not their components.  But if you want to write $K$ as a matrix, by exploiting the fact that since $K(x,y) = \varphi(x) \cdot \varphi(y)$, then the elements of that matrix have indicies ranging from $1$ to $n$.  I would have phrased the statement as $K_{ij}$ is positive definite, but saying it the way the author did is understandable.

Comment: "there is a mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$ , $N\gg n$ such that $K(x,y)=\varphi(x)\cdot\varphi(y)$". This says that the RKHS of any p.d. kernel is finite-dimensional, which is obviously false. This proof is deeply flawed.